# LazyInitializationException when try to retrieve child Entities within the same method inside a Spring @Service class annotated with @Transactional

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I get `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` in a service class in my spring-boot project. Though I've seen a number of questions regarding this Exception, nothing could be found which is similar to my situation.

I'm trying to load a collection of child entities inside a `@Transactional` annotated service method as below.

```
@Override
public Order addOrderPayment(OrderPaymentRQ form, Integer orderId) {
    Order order = repository.findById(orderId).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
    OrderPayment orderPayment = new OrderPayment();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(form, orderPayment);
    order.getOrderPayments().add(orderPayment); //Exception thrown at this line
    repository.save(order);
    return order;
}
```

The particular exception is thrown at `order.getOrderPayments()`.

This happens when I try to do an integration test as follows.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class OrdersRestControllerTest {

final Integer EDIT_ID = 2;

@Autowired
MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
ObjectMapper mapper;

@Autowired
CarsService carsService;

@Autowired
OrdersService ordersService;

@Test
public void removeOrderPayment() throws Exception {
    OrderPaymentRQ payment = new OrderPaymentRQ();
    payment.setDescription("advance payment");
    BigDecimal amount = BigDecimal.valueOf(2000.50);
    payment.setAmount(amount);
    payment.setPaymentMethod(PaymentMethod.CASH);
    payment.setDate(LocalDate.now());

    Order order = ordersService.findById(EDIT_ID).get();
    ordersService.addOrderPayment(payment, EDIT_ID); //This line causes the exception
    OrderPayment toDelete = ordersService.getOrderPayments(EDIT_ID).get(0);

    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(delete("/orders/" + EDIT_ID + "/orderPayments/" + toDelete.getId()).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(EDIT_ID)))
            .andReturn();

    Order orderReturned = mapper.readValue(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString(), Order.class);
    assertEquals(order.getPayments().subtract(toDelete.getAmount()), orderReturned.getPayments());

}
}
```

Entity relationship is as follows(a unidirectional OneToMany).

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Order implements Serializable{
     @Getter
     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
     @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
     @OrderBy("date DESC")
     List<OrderPayment> orderPayments = new ArrayList<>();

     other properties...
}

@Data
@Entity
public class OrderPayment implements Serializable{
    properties...
}
```

My understanding is that the Transaction shouldn't have closed at the line where the exception is thrown because it is inside the same `@Transactional` method.

The exception is not thrown when I annotate my test class with `@Transactional`. Doing so do not persist data to the database, So I cannot guarantee the correct behavior at production.

Could you please help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

## EDIT: Added repository

```
public interface OrdersRepository extends CustomRepository<Order, Integer> {
}

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CustomRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<T> {

}
```

Comment: can you share your repository?

Comment: @AmerQarabsa I have added the repository too in the question now

Comment: i do not see you have transactional on your service method

Comment: As noted above there is no `@Transactional` on the service method posted so post all relevant code. Additionally where is `addOrderPayment(..)` called from.

Comment: I cannot see an Transactional annotation on your service method addOrderPayment. If you put Transactional  to your test each test method will do a rollback after the execution

Comment: I have added the @Transactional annotation at class level, so no need to add it to idividual methods too.

Comment: @Transactional annotation is not present on service method.